# narrowing a table's column in emacs

Tags: emacs

I have a table in emacs and I am trying to narrow some of the columns, say by 7 characters. I tried to do this by using <kbd>C-7</kbd> <kbd>M-x</kbd> `table-narrow-cell` command. However, it says that:

> Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size

Does anyone know what I need to do? Do I need to change something in the `.emacs` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to do the same with a 3x200 table, and get the same result. One function in the table-narrow-cell implementation (table--vertical-cell-list) is recursive, and it looks like when the table is large enough, it blows up. I tried increasing the value of `max-specpdl-size` (see documentation at the end of [Section 11.3 of GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/elisp-manual-21/elisp_141.html)), but it made no difference.

Will org-mode tables be good enough for your purposes instead?

---

Update: I made a typo in the variable name when trying to modify the variable's value. Chaging the `max-specpdl-size` to 10000, I was able to use the function. If this is not an operation you are expecting to do very often, you can change it on the fly: `M-:`, `(setq max-specpdl-size 10000)`, resize table. Alternatively, you can find a safe value, and add it to .emacs.